# In Europe, do trains/buses get transported by ferries with the passengers inside?

Tags: trains, ferries

I'm interested mainly in the route between Ireland and the UK by combined train/bus and ferry.

Does the train/bus drive onto the ship and get transported altogether with the passengers inside, or do the passengers exit the train/bus and board the ship as a foot passenger from the harbor would?

Comment: On all ferries I have ever been, the passengers are not allowed to stay in the vehicle.

Comment: Train passengers exit at the ferry terminal and board the ferry as foot passengers https://www.seat61.com/train-and-ferry-to-dublin.htm. Coach/ferry might depend on the departure point/destination and operator but can be thru-coach service with the same coach throughout your journey https://www.stenaline.co.uk/coach-and-sail but you’ll still need to exit the coach for the actual crossing

Comment: @Traveller: but this thru-coach service implies, as Hilmar indicates above, that the passenger have to exit the coach? That is, cannot for example sleep the whole journey?

Comment: Train cars are heavy, so it would be to costly to transport. As far as I remember, the Port of Dublin has no passenger train station and no train tracks inside the port to load/off load trains. In Holyhead, you get off the ferry and walk over to the train (all inside the port building if I remember correctly).

Comment: @MarkJohnson Train wagons don't add more dead weight per passenger than regular cars and compared to the total weight of a ferry, the train car weight is probably close to insignificant. There are not too many train ferries still operating in Europe, but historically, there have been 22 train ferry connections in Germany alone and 19 in Denmark. In most cases, the ferries have been replaced by bridges and not cancelled because train cars are too heavy.

Comment: The 'Night Ferry' was a train which ran both ways between London Victoria and Paris Gare du Nord stations from 1936 to 1980 although interrupted by World War 2. It had first-class sleeping cars which were carried across the Channel in a train ferry ship. The sleeping passengers remained in their beds during the crossing. Most were awakened by the noise from the cars being chained to, and later, unchained from, the deck of the ship's hold. Second-class non-sleeping passengers had to detrain, board the ferry and board the onward train on the other side.

Comment: Ireland also has a different track gauge than the UK or France and a generally slow rail network. Those factors would weigh much more heavily against train ferries than the weight of the railcars themselves…

Comment: @Relaxed  train connections both sides of the Irish Sea ferries seem to be slow services stopping everywhere, and they don't run right to the dock. The same is broadly true of the English channel ports. So to run trains onto these ferries (again) would require investment in infrastructure as well as rolling stock

Comment: @ChrisH-UK Yes, that too of course and the existence of the tunnel would also make these investments very questionable. But my point is that for Ireland the break of gauge adds a whole other level of complexity. Trains certainly did go all the way to the harbour in [Calais](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gare_de_Calais-Maritime) and cross the English Channel on a ferry. I don't think that was ever the case for Ireland.

Comment: @Hilmar there's a ferry between Konstanz and Meersburg where you're not allowed to leave the bus if you got on via the public bus.

Comment: @Federico a lot of single-deck ferries are like that, often crossing rivers.  If everyone got off the bus after it drove on, they'd need to get straight back on again as the crossing is so short.  The Sandbanks  ferry at Poole Harbour (England) is the same, though I've only done it by bike.

Comment: @ChrisH-UK I think anyone who has driven along the western coast of Norway can attest to the same. Lots of fjord and strait crossings that take 10-30 minutes, on relatively small single-deck ferries. Many people just stay in their cars and buses.

Comment: @Hilmar: the ferry from Helsingør to Helsinborg used to take the full train (split in two). Passengers were free to remain on the train or walk around the ferry.

Comment: @Hilmar: the main train connection from Germany to Denmark crosses on ferry from Puttgarden to Rødby (carriages are split into multiple segments). Same as what MartinArgerami says, passengers could stay in the train or go upstairs to the ferry decks.

Answer (score 22):

As with the general big areas questions the answer is 'it varies'.
With the longer crossings, where buses go on car decks below the waterline there is a common rule that all passengers, including drivers, have to leave the vehicles and go to the same decks as foot passenger. A general rule but I have heard about exceptions on this as well.

On most crossings train passengers will use the ferry as a foot passenger and the train will not enter the ferry. Some long distance bus lines work with this system as well.

On some smaller crossings local buses may travel on the deck of a ferry in which case the bus passengers stay in the bus.

There are or were a few ferries which did transport trains on the ferries, I remember one between Germany and Copenhagen, it may have been within Denmark, where the train drove onto the ferry and the train passengers were given the option to stay in the train on go out onto the ferry, most of the ferries in Denmark are replaced by bridges and this line is one of them.
It used to be more common in the past but it has not been the case for most lines that used to do this for a long time. And I doubt it has ever been between Ireland and Great Britain.

So if you travel by train and ferry prepare for walking off the train onto the ferry, if you travel by coach / long distance bus, expect to leave the bus on the ferry but you might also be asked to walk onto the ferry with your luggage.

Comment: A footnote, between North Island and South Island, New Zealand, passengers train do not use the ferry but goods trains do, so I doubt it is a weight issue.

Comment: The Copenhagen-Hamburg trains used the Rødby-Puttgarden ferries until 2019. A tunnel is under construction. The seasonal Malmö-Berlin trains used Trelleborg-Sassnitz until 2019, then the pandemic triggered a termination of the ferry.

Comment: @Willeke My hunch is that the "weight of cargo" to "weight of train" ratio is different for passenger versus freight trains, so weight might be a factor still.

Comment: I guess it is more easy of handling. Most train cargo is not going to walk on their own legs from the train onto the ferry, while the passengers do.

Comment: The train from mainland Italy to Sicily does drive onto the ferry. According to the Man in Seat 61 you could stay on the train in the past but he suspects they may have tightened up the procedure now.

https://www.seat61.com/Italy.htm#london-to-sicily-by-train also has a picture of the train on the ferry.

Comment: @Willeke you need to stop refusing or voting down good answers. While OP wrote that they are mostly interested by the UK/Ireland route, the title of the question is about Europe in general, and the body says “**mostly** interested…”. All the other answers which have been deleted would have been useful for future readers.

Comment: @jcaron, the three answers I did put a comment under did mention one train on ferry (each) and were no more than comments. They were no valid answers to the question. I did not further act against them, I just pointed it out to them. More than that, the information is now in the comments.

Comment: When I've travelled by coach and ferry, my main luggage had to stay on the bus (in the compartment underneath), and I took a small bag with me, similar to travelling by air. I can't remember if we were instructed to take our hand luggage, or if it was just assumed.

Comment: There's a lot of small islands in Denmark, so I really doubt whether it's most of the ferries that have been replaced by bridges. But to my knowledge all Danish islands that have trains running on them are connected by bridges. The only Danish island I can think of that has long distance buses going to it without a bridge is Bornholm. I have no idea how passengers are handled on that ferry (there are two ferries to Bornholm, but I think most of the buses go through Sweden).

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity If I don't count wrong, of the 18 previously operated train ferries in Denmark, 10 have been replaced with bridges (often one bridge has replaced multiple ferries), 6 were operated on train lines, which have now been decommisioned, hence no use for a train ferry either, and only two train ferries have been abandoned (Hirtshals-Kristiansand and Frederikshavn-Gothenburg), but these two ferries were only used for freight.

Comment: The Copenhagen–Germany train you mention may have been a non-direct route. Up until the opening of the [Great Belt Fixed Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Belt_Bridge) in 1997 (for rail), trains crossing between Zealand and Funen went on the [Great Belt ferries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Belt_ferries), and passengers could indeed choose to stay on the train or go on deck. The crossing took around 50 minutes, if memory serves. Direct trains to Hamburg and beyond went via Rødby–Puttgarden, but you could go Copenhagen–Kolding–Hamburg or similar via the Great Belt.

Comment: You're probably thinking of the train-ferry from Fehman to Denmark (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vogelfluglinie) but it stopped running in 2019.

Comment: @Arno Typically, a freight train is (a lot) heavier than a passenger train, because the locomotive is heavier, the cars are heavier, the loads are heavier, and there's more cars.

Comment: They have a bridge now but a while back (30 years ago) I took a train from Copenhagen to Oslo and the train went by ferry IIRC (it was the middle of the night) and we all stayed on the train for the short jaunt across from Helsingfør to Helsingborg.  I also took a train from Hamburg to Copenhagen the night before and that train also went on a ferry IIRC and we did not leave the train.  And later on that trip Stockholm to Hamburg, again by ferry for the bits across the water.

Comment: @Arno Does the weight of the locomotive matter? I've seen train ferries, but they just ship the cars, and use different locomotives on different sides.

Answer (score 15):

The main ferry link between the UK and Republic of Ireland for passengers is from Holyhead to Dublin. Other routes include Liverpool-Dublin and Fishguard/Pembroke to Rosslare. This answer concentrates mainly on the Holyhead-Dublin link, primarily from to personal experience.

**Trains**

While there are rail connections to all the mentioned UK ports, no railway carriages are carried on board ferries. The main reason for this is that Irish railways use a different track gauge.[1] If you took a carriage onto the ferry, you couldn't take it any further than the other port. As a result, passengers travelling by railway are expected to alight the train and then embark the ferry themselves.

At Holyhead, the platforms of the railway station were placed along either side of the inner harbour[2], this allowed a cross-platform interchange between boat trains and the ferries. This arrangement survived until the late 20th century, when larger ferries (suited to roll-on-roll-off vehicle traffic) were unable to access the inner harbour, and new gantries were built in the outer harbour instead. The railway station and platforms remained in the same place, however. The gantry built for Stena Line's [HSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High-speed_Sea_Service) Ferries in the 1990s was relatively near ferry terminal, and foot passengers could walk the short distance. Current ferries have gantries further out, and foot passengers are shuttled to the road deck of these ferries by a bus, and passengers then climb the stairs to the passenger deck. The bus does not sail with the ferry: it is removed before the ferry sails.

On the Irish side, there is no rail connection to Dublin Port. (The nearby port of Dun Laoghaire has a railway station, but ferries stopped serving this port in 2015.) Irish Ferries have gantries that include a gangplank for passengers to embark and disembark directly from the passenger deck, though some moorings require passengers to embark/disembark via the road deck. Stena use a [shuttle bus](https://www.stenaline.co.uk/customer-service/at-the-port/how-do-foot-passengers-access-the-ferry) between the ferry and the passenger terminal, as at Holyhead.

I understand that Rosslare's railway station is close to the harbour, as is Fishguard Harbour station. Pembroke Dock station is a short walk from the harbour. As above, passengers will walk from the railway station to the ferry terminal.

**Buses and Coaches**

There are no timetabled public bus services between the Republic of Ireland and Great Britain. There is a limited scheduled coach service[3], and some private coaches will operate. These drive onto the ferry with other road traffic, but will be subject to the same regulations as other vehicles, which require all passengers to leave the road deck and remain on the passenger deck while sailing. Passengers will presumably return to the coaches at the same time that car passengers do, on approaching their destination.

**Foot Passenger Numbers in General**

The growth in use of roll-on-roll-off car ferries, and cheap short-distance air travel, means that foot passenger traffic (e.g. from rail connections) is greatly reduced compared with decades ago. As this is a shrinking proportion of ferries' business, it does not warrant any significant spending on new infrastructure for foot passenger connections.

---

[1]: This was made law by the  [Railway Regulation Act of 1846](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Railway_Regulation_(Gauge)_Act_1846)

[2]: See https://www.flickr.com/photos/blue-diesels/5862917181/ for an example of how close the railway and ferries were

[3]: National Express offer coach travel between London and Dublin: https://www.nationalexpress.com/en/destinations/dublin/london-to-dublin

Answer (score 9):

Everyone has forgotten the Sicilian train-ferry?

Trains from mainland Italy to Sicily are taken on a ferry between Villa San Giovanni (mainland) and Messina Maritima (Sicily).

Video: [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=feRAar21U1A) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9grLtdPWYhg) and many others on Youtube

Seat61 page: https://www.seat61.com/trains-and-routes/trains-to-sicily.htm

Currently, the trains that use this route are:

- ICN 1955 Roma-Siracusa, Villa S. Giovanni d 03.50 - Messina Centrale a 05.15
- ICN 1959 Roma-Siracusa, Villa S. Giovanni d 06.35 - Messina Centrale a 08.05
- ICN 1963 Milano-Siracusa, Villa S. Giovanni d 11.05 - Messina Centrale a 12.45
- IC 723 Roma-Palermo, Villa S. Giovanni d 14.30 - Messina Centrale a 15.35
- IC 727 Roma-Siracusa, Villa S. Giovanni d 18.25 - Messina Centrale a 19.35

And in the opposite direction:

- IC 728 Palermo-Roma, Messina Centrale d 10.10 - Villa S. Giovanni a 11.20
- IC 724 Siracusa-Roma, Messina Centrale d 13.10 - Villa S. Giovanni a 14.20
- ICN 1962 Siracusa-Milano, Messina Centrale d 16.45 - Villa S. Giovanni a 18.15
- ICN 1956 Siracusa-Roma, Messina Centrale d 22.10 - Villa S. Giovanni a 23.35
- ICN 1960 Siracusa-Roma, Messina Centrale d 00.35 - (passing through Villa S. Giovanni) - Salerno a 06.42

(All times from Trenitalia pdf timetables "In Treno Tutt'Italia")

Comment: And do passengers remain in the carriages during the crossing, or alight?

Comment: They remain in the carriages. Personal experience: it can be a little uncomfortable because, as carriages are detached from engine, AC is switched off.

Comment: 'Everyone has forgotten the Sicilian train-ferry?' No, there were 2 answers allready. Unfortunatly, despite the fact that 'In Europe' was originally part of the question (and now removed), they were encouraged to delete their answers and replace them as a comment.

Comment: The Sicilian rail ferry is one connection and a post just mentioning that train ferry does not answer the question, which indicated from the start that UK Ireland is the main focus. This is the third post on that ferry which should have been posted as a comment, and is already posted as such before this post was posted. You can edit to include more general Europe information.

Comment: @Willeke Clearly it's an answer to the headline question and a useful addition to this Q&A, no need to repeat what has already been said in other answers to satisfy some moderator idiosyncratic preferences. Maybe the fact that it's the third time someone sees the relevance together with all the votes could be a cue that it's time for you to stop forcing your judgment on everybody else? Besides, we also have guidelines against long comment threads and it's only a matter of time before you or Jonathan remove them so this is definitely better posted as an answer.

Comment: @Relaxed, we also have rules about quality for answers. I am not forcing, I am pointing out that the posts do not meet the required quality standards and no, I am not going to stop with what I see as my duty.

Comment: @Willeke I think your duty as moderator is exactly the opposite: Showing restraint, letting the community regulate itself and being able to respect its decisions (+7 at this point…). This answer clearly meets all quality standards, it's clear, informative, well formatted, written in English, supported by relevant links, not spammy, polite, respectful *and objectively addresses the headline question as written*.

Comment: Having an opinion or good faith disagreements on how it could be improved is one thing but suggesting that this *does not meet quality standards* is completely unreasonable and borderline abusive coming from a moderator. If you want to improve quality, I suggest working on the typos and layout of your own answers.

Comment: @Willeke It should also be noted that the OP, a member of 9 years, reverted the removal of the 'In Europe' from the title. So obviously the OP is **also** interested in European samples. I personally found the *'Night Ferry' between London Victoria and Paris Gare du Nord* answer of interest, but that answer was also suffered the fate of your 'required quality standards'.

Comment: @Willeke Can you explain which of the quality standards this answer doesn't meet? The fact that OP is mainly interested in the UK and IE doesn't make it off-topic

Comment: @NicolasFormichella, This answer, as well as those now deleted, picked one tiny detail out of a big question and answered only that one detail. Besides that, the detail is not even within the area OP named as main interest, but that is not the main reason it does not answer the question.

Comment: @Willeke Sorry... what? How does that not answer the *In Europe, do trains/buses get transported by ferries with the passengers inside?* main question? Seeing that main question and the fact that it's only an *interest*, the question is very generic, and is perfectly answerable by non-UK answers

Comment: @Willeke If you take the headline question literally, the fact that such a ferry does presently exist is not a detail, it's the *only* relevant fact. By contrast, finding that UK-Ireland ferries do not carry trains doesn't answer the question. You would need to show that no ferry anywhere in Europe carry trains to answer negatively. Even hedging as you did in your own answer is misleading if all you have are past examples you're not sure about. It's really rich to pretend the only answer with a verifiable contemporary example is “low quality”.